# Doctrine2: Native SQL alias in SELECT

Tags: php, sql, native, doctrine-orm

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('Default_Model_School', 's');
$rsm->addMetaResult('s', 'distance', 'distance'); // no
$rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'establishment_name', 'establishment_name');

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery(
                'SELECT *, a*b AS distance
                 FROM schools',
                 $rsm);
```

I am trying to get distance out from the query.

I tried the following, which works but breaks my other queries...

```
$rsm->addMetaResult('s', 'distance', 'distance');
```

and added the column to my entity...

```
/**
* @var string $distance
* @Column(type="string")
*/
private $distance;
```

This does not seem right as the column does not exist.

Comment: Just a though but what are you trying to do that at a db level? I'll go for either storing distance in database or compute it on the fly in my entity, it should be cheap.